# How to show custom field values in user account in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I add a custom field in woo commerce add products page with the name of number of tokens. Now these tokens are saving in the database successfully. Now I want to show these tokens into user accounts like **total token: 50**.

Here is the code I add for add the custom field values into database

```
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">'; 

    //Custom Product Number Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_number_field',
            'placeholder' => 'Number of Tokens',
            'label' => __('Number of Tokens', 'woocommerce'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min' => '0'
            )
        )
    );
  echo '</div>';



}


function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id)
    {
    // Custom Product Number Field
    $woocommerce_custom_product_number_field = $_POST['_custom_product_number_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_number_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field));

    }
```

Now I want to show the _custom_product_number_field saving values into user account. Please let me know how can I do that

Thanks

Comment: Where in the My Account page do you want to show the custom field?  In the 'Account Details" TAB ?

Comment: like this http://prntscr.com/h4q7i8 @AndrewSchultz

Comment: Please specify the URL of that page. Is it /my-account/orders/ ?

Comment: no it is with /my-account @AndrewSchultz

Comment: What version of WooCommerce are you using?

Comment: latest one @AndrewSchultz

Comment: There shouldn't be any recent orders showing on the My Account page until you click on the Orders TAB.  The first page you see is the Dashboard.

Comment: Ok so do you want to show the total number of tokens from all the customers' orders?

Comment: NO, I want to show the tokens to the user which he/she buy thats it @AndrewSchultz and I donot have now idea how to do it. If you have any solution then please tell me